# long of tooth and wisdom

Tags: meaning

Is there any evidence that the expression "long of tooth" is commonly used to mean older and wiser with some emphasis on the wisdom that comes with age?

Comment: What research have you done? You must show your own research in your post or your question will be at risk of being closed.

Comment: The *truly* wise old man would have realised decades earlier that receding gums are primarily caused by inadequate dental care (and smoking), so he'd have taken steps to avoid developing the condition.

Comment: Is there any evidence that the expression “long of tooth” is commonly used at all?

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet: It had [no significant currency C19 or earlier](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=long+of+tooth&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=50&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clong%20of%20tooth%3B%2Cc0) (and not much since then, by comparison with *long **in the** tooth*), so I think it's best seen as a latter-day *[mock-] **poetic***  usage.

Answer (score 3):

There is an idiom **'long in the tooth**'. "If you describe someone as long in the tooth, you are saying unkindly or humorously that they are old or getting old".(https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/long-in-the-tooth)

It has the meaning, **old or ageing** (*informal*, disapproval) and has nothing to do with wisdom.

**Etymology:**
Possibly from the practice of examining the length of horses’ teeth when estimating their ages: an old horse has long, rectangular incisors, and their occlusion angle is steep.

Compare: don't look a gift horse in the mouth.(https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/long_in_the_tooth)